# Why dying HDD keep lagging entire system while I have Windows and all of the stuff running from 2 other SSD's?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

So while I'm waiting for a new HDD I have a general questing why is does this? Every time when HDD response time goes through the roof to 100% my system is quietly waiting for him to unlag which I find kinda strange if you ask me and wondering why ft it is like that.

On a side note, I interested why these programs that will scan HDD for bad sectors didn't show the signs of it dying because I did the scan a couple of days before

Comment: That a partially defect HDD blocks Windows is nothing new. I am not sure if this is an OS problem or hardware problem but it always was this way. The main reason for those delays is that the HDD tries to recover the data for a very long time and so a request that usually takes may be half a second now takes 20-30 seconds.

Comment: Can be file system related too. How did you determine drive is dying exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You really have 2 distinct questions here

1. Why is it laggy -
   because it's expecting a response & not getting one, so it waits… & waits… until one arrives.
2. Why doesn't it report failure -
   because that's not its job. chkdsk's job is to fix the file system. It will keep on trying to do that whether it's possible or not. It doesn't know any better. [It will incidentally sacrifice any & all data in its attempt, file recovery is also not its job.]
   If you want reports on imminent failure, use a SMART monitor. That will report based on criteria indicative of a slow or rapid fail of the underlying disk's 'mechanics'.

**TL:DR** Computers are not intelligent. They do what they're told & **only** what they're told.